How to select XML tags value from table in oracle?
I have xml value stored in oracle table as below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalon="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE TRADE>
<TRADE>
    <SOME_TAGS>
        <TAG>
        ...
        </TAG>
    </SOME_TAGS>
    <QTYS>
        <QTY TYPE="Commission">
            <NUM>0.0000</NUM>
            <ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID>
        <QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TransactionFee">
            <NUM>3.0000</NUM>
            <ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID>
        <QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TFee">
            <NUM>0.0000</NUM>
            <ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID>
        <QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="BFee">
            <NUM>1.0000</NUM>
            <ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID>
        <QTY>       
    </QTYS>
</TRADE>

I want to write select query to get those QTY tags whose NUM value is not 0 and put it to columns. Values in columns depends on non-zero qtys.There can be trades who might have all 4 qtys with non-zero then there will be all values in columns or there can be trades which has few non-zeros qty so add only those who has non-zero values
I tried to get the data using extractvalue function , i can extract value per tag but I want to make it more generic and dont want to write for extractvalue function for each tag and then check if its num value is 0 or not.
Can I use something like xpath ? how to use this?
My expected result is as below

In above example, TradeA has only one set of qty non-zero value so it has selected only one set in select query whereas TradeB has 2 set of non-zero Qty values so it has added values in that many columns and so on.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the sample XML data that matches your expected output; the expected output as markdown formatted text or table (and not an image); and an explanation of how to transform the input to the sample output as, currently, it is unclear where the Trade amount comes from and many of the other values do not appear in the sample data.

You can use XMLTABLE to get the values as rows and then PIVOT to transpose them to columns:
SELECT type1, type1_amount, type1_ccy,
       type2, type2_amount, type2_ccy,
       type3, type3_amount, type3_ccy,
       type4, type4_amount, type4_ccy
FROM   (
         SELECT t.ROWID AS id,
                x.type,
                x.amount,
                x.currency,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ROWID ORDER BY x.id) AS rn
         FROM   table_name t
                CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
                  '/TRADE/QTYS/QTY'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml)
                  COLUMNS
                    id       FOR ORDINALITY,
                    type     VARCHAR2(50) PATH './@TYPE',
                    amount   NUMBER       PATH './NUM',
                    currency VARCHAR2(3)  PATH './ID[@CLASS="Currency"]'
                ) x
         WHERE  amount > 0
       )
       PIVOT (
         MAX(type),
         MAX(amount) AS amount,
         MAX(currency) AS ccy
         FOR rn IN (
           1 AS type1,
           2 AS type2,
           3 AS type3,
           4 AS type4
         )
       )

Which, for the sample data (assuming you have valid XML data including having closing tags to match all the opening tags):
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalon="no"?>
<TRADE>
    <SOME_TAGS><TAG>...</TAG></SOME_TAGS>
    <QTYS>
        <QTY TYPE="Commission"><NUM>1.3340</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TransactionFee"><NUM>0.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TFee"><NUM>0.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="BFee"><NUM>0.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>       
    </QTYS>
</TRADE>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalon="no"?>
<TRADE>
    <SOME_TAGS><TAG>...</TAG></SOME_TAGS>
    <QTYS>
        <QTY TYPE="Commission"><NUM>3.4000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TransactionFee"><NUM>0.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TFee"><NUM>3.4000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">HKD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="BFee"><NUM>0.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>       
    </QTYS>
</TRADE>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalon="no"?>
<TRADE>
    <SOME_TAGS><TAG>...</TAG></SOME_TAGS>
    <QTYS>
        <QTY TYPE="Commission"><NUM>3.3000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TransactionFee"><NUM>2.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="TFee"><NUM>0.0000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">HKD</ID></QTY>
        <QTY TYPE="BFee"><NUM>3.4000</NUM><ID CLASS="Currency">USD</ID></QTY>       
    </QTYS>
</TRADE>' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



TYPE1
TYPE1_AMOUNT
TYPE1_CCY
TYPE2
TYPE2_AMOUNT
TYPE2_CCY
TYPE3
TYPE3_AMOUNT
TYPE3_CCY
TYPE4
TYPE4_AMOUNT
TYPE4_CCY




Commission
1.334
USD
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null


Commission
3.4
USD
TFee
3.4
HKD
null
null
null
null
null
null


Commission
3.3
USD
TransactionFee
2
USD
BFee
3.4
USD
null
null
null



fiddle
